# Datagridview rowcount showing 0 even when there is a valid datasource

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, rowcount

I have a dynamically created DataGridView that has a valid DataSource with one row bound to it. However, it is returning me 0 when I am doing a rowcount on the DataGridView.

```
dgResult.DataSource = resultDt; // a datatable containing one row
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(dgResult); 
int rows = dgResult.Rows.Count; // returning 0 always!
```

Can someone please tell me where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue. I was displaying the grid in a tabbed page that was not selected. Unless the grid is visible, it does not raise the rowadded event (which is weird!) durnig databinding. I selected the tab page before doing the databind, and the rowcount worked.

Comment: i am facing the same problem, i am displaying the datagrid in tablelayout, can u tell me the way to solve it.

Comment: how you did this can you please let us now my grid view is in tab and returning 1 always row count how to count rows of gridview that are present inTABS

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = resultDt;

dgResult.DataSource = bindingSource;
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(dgResult); 

var c = dgResult.Rows.Count;
```

The binding source is what's responsible for syncing your data with the control. You want to use it, rather than trying to assign the table directly to the control.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the problem.

Comment: My guess would be that you are somehow disposing of your data before it is being bound. Post up your code that fills the datatable and I'll take a look. Make sure you leave out the connectionstring and include your declarations as well so I can take a look at the scope of the variables.