# DataGridView RowsAdded event not fired?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a table layout on my Form in which I use a Datagrid to show the data. The first time when I assign a datasource to it, it works well, but when I assign a Datasource to the DataGrid a second time, it doesn't call the **RowsAdded event of Datagrid** and Datagrid doesn't show anything except its header and Datagrid shows the `RowCount` is 0.

I found a similar problem here also:

[Datagridview rowcount showing 0 even when there is a valid datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212086/datagridview-rowcount-showing-0-even-when-there-is-a-valid-datasource)

EDIT #1

My code is

```
gridProjectEdit.DataSource = null;
gridProjectEdit.Columns.Clear();
gridProjectEdit.Rows.Clear();            
gridProjectEdit.Refresh();

if(dt!=null)
dt.Clear();
dt=methodCaller.GetProjectData(); //get the data
gridProjectEdit.DataSource = dt;  //copying datatable
```

Comment: please update the question with the code

Comment: i am assigning the data source using above code every time.

Comment: in second time have you check you have records in `DataTable` or not?

Comment: I have checked that it contains rows, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212086/datagridview-rowcount-showing-0-even-when-there-is-a-valid-datasource

Comment: I highly recommend you to add another grid to your form and fill this grid instead of your existing grid. Your problem is very strange, that's why no one can help you. You should also try using some **foreach** loop to loop through all the rows of your **dt**, try printing them out manually to see what rows are in there.

Comment: i tried with the another grid also and it is behaving the same like first one.

Answer (score 1):

Rows added event is fired when rows are added using the dataGridView.Rows.Add() method.
You should use DataSourceChanged event to fire the change of the datasource of the dataGridView.
Also checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasourcechanged.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: `RowsAdded` is also fired when the `DataSource` is changed (of course if it has some data).