# DataGridView.Rows.Count is 0

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to read the content of an excel file (I must process the data not show it) but the number of rows is 0. I did show the data in the UI and the rows didn't have a number.

```
string src = "the path;";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + src +
                                       "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"");

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [RENNES4_wk13$]", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
int rows = dgv.Rows.Count;
int cells = dgv.Rows[0].Cells.Count;//ArgumentOutOfRange why?
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: For a start it doesn't look like you're ever opening you're connection?

Comment: it wasn't in the tutorial, just started work on this today. Can you show me?

Comment: You dont need to open connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```
        string src = @"C:\SampleData\us-500.xls";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + src +
                                          ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

        //con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [MySheet$]", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        var dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

        // Add data grid view as child control on form, flow Layout Panel is placed on windows form 
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int cells = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
```

Comment: hold on, it works for dataGridView1 even without the binding stuff but for new DataGridView it doesn't? how come?

Comment: you have to add the new DataGridView() to as a child control of any other control in window form

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = resultDt;
```

in your case:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

and:

```
dgResult.DataSource = bindingSource;
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(dgResult); 

var c = dgResult.Rows.Count;
```

The binding source is what's responsible for syncing your data with the control. You want to use it, rather than trying to assign the table directly to the control.

Reference:

[Datagridview rowcount showing 0 even when there is a valid datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212086/datagridview-rowcount-showing-0-even-when-there-is-a-valid-datasource)

Comment: .DataBind() is not defined what am I missing?

Comment: ohh it is DataGridView not girdview

Comment: try this: int rows = dgv.RowCount