# Why is grid.Rows.Count always 0?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataSet` which is not null. It have 16 rows,

[image]

but my grid have no rows. I have `bindingSource`, here is some code:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //ds is DataSet
grid.DataSource = bindingSource;

double sum1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum1 += Convert.ToDouble(grid.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
}
```

When I start debugging, when it comes to `i < grid.Rows.Count` it just jump out of for loop. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: instead of `grid.Rows.Count` try `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

Comment: Perhaps `grid.DataBind()` is needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.Rows.Count is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130156/datagridview-rows-count-is-0)

Comment: What is bindingSource? Why not simply `grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`? Also check if it needs `grid.DataBind();` to actually reflect to gridview

Comment: What is the purpose of using BindingSource in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to directly assign the data table to `DataGridView` `DataSource`..

```
grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

double sum1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum1 += Convert.ToDouble(grid.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);
}
```

It Works....

Comment: Yeah... You are all right. There is no need for binding source.