# Why isn't datagridview.rowcount always returning 0, regardless of number of rows present?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable, datasource

I create a bindingsource object, set its datasource to a datatable which is populated with data from a SQL DB, and then use the bindingsource object as the datasource for a datagridview. It works correctly, and I see the rows populating in my datagridview, but I found that the rowcount of my datagridview was always 0, regardless of the number of rows present.

Initially I was setting the datagridview datasource to the datatable directly. Based on some of the comments I found in [DataGridView.Rows.Count is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130156/datagridview-rows-count-is-0) I created a bindingsource object first and then used that as the datasource for my datagridview.

```
 // Load the data from SqlDataReader into the data table.
dataTable.Load(dataReader);

// Sets Data Grid View equal to data table
this.dgvQualReports.DataSource = dataTable;

//Populates Data Grid View
dgvQualReports.AutoGenerateColumns = true;





//   BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
//  bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

//   dvgQualReports.DataSource = bindingSource;




// Close the SqlDataReader.
dataReader.Close();

int bs = dvgQualReports.Rows.Count;
```

No error message, but when I stop the code directly after the last line, it has bs=0. I expected it to be 1.

Comment: I did. Still nothing.

Comment: Where are you running this code?  What does `dataTable.Rows.Count` return?

Comment: Did you read your title??

Comment: I messed up the title. Should read why IS datagridview always returning zero. Is there a way to edit the title?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a typo in your code:
this.**dgv**QualReports.DataSource = dataTable;
and
int bs = **dvg**QualReports.Rows.Count;

Are you sure you're working with the same DataGridView, don't you have another one on a form?